# How can I bind Gio.Settings of TextBuffer or TextView?

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, pygtk

I'm trying to bind a TextView to the key "text" by TextBuffer. I get the text, but this property is not recorded.

```
widget = self.builder.get_object('textbuffer_text')
settings.bind("text", widget, "text", Gio.SettingsBindFlags.DEFAULT)
```

I would be grateful for any hints or help

Answer (score 2):

I set it manually, but it is annoying.

```
widget = self.builder.get_object('textbuffer_text')
#~ self.settings.bind("text", widget, "text", Gio.SettingsBindFlags.DEFAULT)
text = self.settings.get_string("text")
widget.set_text(text, len(text))
```

...

```
def on_textbuffer_text_changed (self, widget):
    b,e = widget.get_bounds()
    self.settings.set_string("text", widget.get_text(b,e,False).decode('utf-8'))
```